# Marklogic Diacritic Sensitive search not working for unfiltered searches

Tags: diacritics, marklogic, cts-search

If I do a diacritic sensitive `cts:query` for `cts:search` in unfiltered mode then I get correct result but doing the same in filtered mode gives me incorrect results.
For example :

```
cts:search($data,($cts:query('unfiltered','diacritic-sensitive')))
returns incorrect results.
```

but :

```
cts:search($data,($cts:query('filtered','diacritic-sensitive')))
returns correct results.
```

So, is there any way to get correct results for unfiltered searches too?

Please find below my details of the code.

```
for $result in cts:search (fn:collection ($searchable-collection), $cts-query, ('unfiltered',     $relevance-score-algo), 0.0)
        order by xs:dateTime ($result//c:created-on) descending
        return $result/element()
```

Where the $cts-query is like this.

```
cts:element-query($element-to-query,
        cts:word-query($search-text,
        $search-options,
        $weight)
```

In options I can pass "diacritic-sensitive" or not.

Comment: Can you provide a little sample xml?

Comment: Please correct sample code as well, it is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

For accurate unfiltered diacritic-sensitive search, you must enable the `fast diacritic sensitive searches` index. Allow reindexing and monitor the database status until it is complete.

The docs have more on [text indexing options](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/text_index) and [unfiltered search](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered).